# How to use Twitter typeahead to open a new page after autocompletion

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, autocomplete, typeahead

I'm using Twitter's Typeahead library, and just as a toy model question: how do I open a new page after a user makes a selection. For example, suppose the user selects "mercury" below, how do I then open this link "https://www.google.com/search?&q=mercury":

```
$('#input').typeahead([
{
name: 'planets',
local: [ "Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune" ]
}
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do something similar to this:

```
    $('#input').on('typeahead:selected', function(e, datum){
            window.location = '/some/directory/'+datum.id;
    });
```

If `datum.id` doesn't work try logging out datum inside the function to see what all you have access to:

```
    console.log(datum);
```

Comment: are there other selectors besides "typeahead:selected". This allows me to select items based on the dropdown list, but it doesn't process "tabs" or "clicks/return-key-presses" directly in the search bar. Thanks!